# Step function implementation in Gekko

Tags: gekko

I am trying to implement something similar to step function in Gekko (IMODE=6).
I have tried If3 and setting custom lower and upper bounds, still no solution could be found in Gekko.

what would you recommend for such a step function or any piecewise function in Gekko?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step functions (or any other input) are permitted in Gekko. If the step function does not depend on a condition but only on a time then you won't need the `if3` function. Here is an example problem with `u_step` that defines the step function.

[image: Step function]

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO()    # create GEKKO model
m.time = np.linspace(0,40,401) # time points

# create GEKKO parameter (step 0 to 2 at t=5)
u_step = np.zeros(401)
u_step[50:] = 2.0
u = m.Param(value=u_step)

# create GEKKO variables
x = m.Var(0.0) 
y = m.Var(0.0) 

# create GEEKO equations
m.Equation(2*x.dt()==-x+u) 
m.Equation(5*y.dt()==-y+x) 

# solve ODE
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve()

# plot results
plt.plot(m.time,u,'g:',label='u(t)')
plt.plot(m.time,x,'b-',label='x(t)')
plt.plot(m.time,y,'r--',label='y(t)')
plt.ylabel('values')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Additional tutorials with [differential equations solved with Gekko](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/PythonDifferentialEquations) are available.